# Responsive site not showing horizontal lines correctly due to scaling issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I am adding responsive feature to a website using css, this website has been their for sometime and now responsive feature is being added to it so that it can support mobile version.

I am facing one issue suppose a have multiple row which are separated by a horizontal line.
in some place i am using `hr` and in some places i am using simply `div` to...

here is a sample link to fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/G2rCT/3/

When i view desktop version then lines exactly show as 1 pixels in height and when i view on mobile then alternative line show as if they are 2 pixels in height.

But when i zoom in it look fine, I thing issue is with the zoom factor. I am using also `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` varied the initial-scale value but it doesn't make any difference.

Am i missing something i thing problem is the way i am using viewport.

Mobile sample can he checked here http://fiddle.jshell.net/G2rCT/4/show/

Comment: Tested your code locally and using the JS Fiddle link you provided, with and without meta tag, and can't recreate the issue on Android 4.4 (both stock and Chrome browsers). What device are you viewing it on?

Comment: I am using android 2.3.7 here is the link which you can try http://fiddle.jshell.net/G2rCT/4/show/ i also tried same on latest mobile opera browser same issue..

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an issue you can solve. Your code is fine.

Below you'll see an image of a few screenshots I took. I ran the Fiddle through Android 2.3.3 and 4.4 on virtual machines, then played with the scaling. The top two pictures are 2.3.3 and 4.4, scaled to 100% resolution. 1 pixel on my screen is 1 pixel on the 'phone'. You can see that the lines are fine (I think the 4.4 screenshot might not have been exactly 1:1, but its clear in the 2.3.3 screenshot)

But below, you will see where I have taken the same device but scaled the phone down, so it was no longer 1:1. You can see the issue you are describing appearing in these screenshots, meaning that the way your phone screen and the scaling is the issue here.

Edit: You might need to load the [image URL in a new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUwIu.png) to see the real thing. I'm not sure how to link a picture on here sorry!

[image: Scaling issues on android]