# Issue with response design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using `hr` tag at various place on responsive site for some reason some lines appear with different thickness as show in example below

[image]

here is fiddle sample :http://fiddle.jshell.net/G2rCT/9/show/

I tested this on android default browser with os 2.3.7
with latest firefox for android and latest Opera

same issue across all browser.. I am not sure why this is happening to line with 1px only if i increase the line height to 2px then is looks fine.

any help in this regard is appreciated

Comment: What does this question have to do with responsive design? It shows exactly the same in every windowsize. But the problem could be that the browser will render it that way.

Comment: It is probably a matter of rendering.

Comment: This is a sample only actually width increases with width of the screen. here is the modified responsive version http://fiddle.jshell.net/G2rCT/10/show/

Comment: It seems you have re-posted the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676735/responsive-site-not-showing-horizontal-lines-correctly-due-to-scaling-issue (and you even got an answer there)

Answer (score 1):

Extract from Normalize.css

```
/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
```

Include the above code in your stylesheet.

[Check out normalize.css as well, while you are at it.](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: It doesn't make any difference to it, it tried but same result.

Comment: I have used hr as well as a div with 1px height but i get same result. Issue is only when i give 1px height to hr or div. if you zoom in then it looks fine.. not sure why is this happening

Comment: Just tested it on my mobile android os 4.3.1 with chrome, looks fine as well. Same for firefox. Looks like its a compatibility issue with android gingerbread.